# ggbiplot worked previously with prcomp, now will not

Tags: r, ggbiplot, prcomp

`ggbiplot` used to work with no problems using `prcomp` but now does not.  All I receive is the following error code:

> Error in plot_label(p = p, data = plot.data, label = label, label.label = label.label,  : 
>     Unsupported class: prcomp

I have installed `ggbiplot` using `dependencies=TRUE` and everything else other posts about similar issues have done but yet I still get this message.

Any help is appreciated.

```
mypca <- prcomp(mydata, center=TRUE, scale.=TRUE)
ggbiplot(mypca, center=TRUE, scale.=TRUE)
```

> Error in plot_label(p = p, data = plot.data, label = label, label.label = label.label,  : 
>     Unsupported class: prcomp

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `ggbiplot` has a `center` nor `scale.` argument. Are you confusing `prcomp` with `ggbiplot` function arguments?

The following works just fine:

```
library(ggbiplot)
pca <- prcomp(USArrests, center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
ggbiplot(pca)
```

[image]

Tested on `ggbiplot_0.55`.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
ggbiplot::ggbiplot(mypca)
```